# how can I loop through this referenced data (tagged episode) in ejs

Tags: node.js, loops, express, ejs

I basically want to display the episodes nested in `tvSeason` which is also nested in `seriesMovie`

```
<% seriesMovie.tvSeasons.forEach(function(tvSeason) { %>
    <h1>
    <%= tvSeason["episodes"].episode_number %>  
    </h1>
<% }) %>


"tvSeasons" : [ 
    {
        "season_id" : "4321",
        "episode_count" : "22",
        "season_number" : "1",
        "overview" : "nothing",
        "image_path" : "grey.jpg",
        "release_date" : "2005-12-24",
        "episodes" : [ 
            {
                "episode_id" : "4553",
                "episode_number" : "1",
                "episode_title" : "rage",
                "image_path" : "rey.jpg",
                "video_path" : "rom.mp4",
                "episode_runtime" : "42"
            }
        ]
]
```

episode_number is not defined

Comment: what have you tried? can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Is "episode_number is not defined" an error?

Comment: sorry it's Cannot read property 'episode_number' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't it work ?

It seems that episodes is an array... So if you want to access the first episode, just indicate the `episode[0]` ...

```
<% seriesMovie.tvSeasons.forEach(function(tvSeason) { %>
    <h1>
    <%= tvSeason["episodes"][0].episode_number %>  
    </h1>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: well i actually want to loop through all episode in the data base. and this <%= tvSeason["episodes"][0].episode_number %> just return an error stating "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Are you able to dump the `season_id` in your loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Because "episodes" is a list holding objects. You should first access the element you want in that list then call episode number upon that. Somethin like this

`tvSeason["episodes"][0].episode_number`

Comment: yea tried that but returning Cannot read property '0' of undefined. But those that mean you cant loop through the episodes?